# 'Smart commits' in phabricator? Commit comment to associate to Maniphest

Tags: git, phabricator, maniphest

I have recently started using Phabricator, having been using Jira for past few years, and perhaps I am applying Jira thinking to Phabricator, but I cannot figure out how to make git commits be associated with a Maniphest task.

In Jira, it is a case of prefixing the commit with the jira task. However this does not seem to work in Phabricator.

Is there a way to achieve this in Phabricator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://phabricator.org/applications/differential/

You can use the Key words `Ref T123` or `Fixes T123` in your commit message to link them automatically.  `Fixes T123` will link and close the task.

Comment: You can also edit a `commit` and associate it with a maniphest task.